# How do I return 404 response if no URL Rewrite Rules are matched

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, jetty, iis-10

I'm running IIS 10 on Windows 2019.  I have the following two rules

```
        <rules>
             <rule name="Reverse Proxy Inbound Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="ServiceName1(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:9090/{R:1}" />
             </rule>
             <rule name="Reverse Proxy Inbound Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="ServiceName2(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:9091/{R:1}" />
             </rule>
         </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

Basically, if neither of these rules are matched, am I able to return a 404 response.  At the minute I'm running Jetty and it is returning

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
> gateway or proxy server.

Comment: Add a third rule to match `.*` and merely return a custom response of 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below rule to set custom page using url rewrite:

```
 <rules>
            <rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="4" statusReason="this is custom error page" statusDescription="test error" />
            </rule>
```

or

```
<rule name="Handle404" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
               
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/path/to/404.html" />
            </rule>
```

and set below code in web.conifg file under <system.webServer> section:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" />
```